# Ensure two fields in a Python class are the same subclass of a given base class using mypy

Tags: python, mypy

Let's say I have the following dataclasses:

```
@dataclass
class Product:
    color: str

@dataclass
class Wrench(Product):
    pass

@dataclass
class Hammer(Product):
    pass
```

I'm trying to create a new dataclass called `Order` with two fields, both fields must have the same subclass of `Product`. I could create the `Order` class like so:

```
@dataclass
class Order:
    primary_product: Product
    secondary_product: Product
```

But this doesn't validate the same `Product` subclass condition I stated above:

```
product1 = Wrench(color="Yellow")
product2 = Hammer(color="Black")

order = Order(primary_product=product1, secondary_product=product2)  # NO ERROR
```

The following implementation of `Order` with [generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html) gets me some of the way there:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

@dataclass
class Order(Generic[T]):
    primary_product: T
    secondary_product: T

product1 = Wrench(color="Yellow")
product2 = Wrench(color="White")
product3 = Hammer(color="Black")

order1 = Order[Wrench](primary_product=product1, secondary_product=product2)
order2 = Order[Wrench](primary_product=product1, secondary_product=product3)  # error: Argument "secondary_product" to "Order" has incompatible type "Hammer"; expected "Wrench"
```

It's annoying to pass the target Product subclass (`Wrench` in the case above) to `Order` on every object initialization. Moreover, this doesn't ensure both fields are products:

```
order1 = Order[int](primary_product=1, secondary_product=2)  # NO ERROR
```

Is there anyway to achieve this or am I pushing the limits of `mypy` and Python's type hints too far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down in the mypy documentation you posted there are two different ways presented. Both are not ideal.

#### First way: use a type bound

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Product)
```

Now the generic parameter can only be a `Product`

```py
order1 = Order[int](primary_product=1, secondary_product=2)
# error: Value of type variable "T" of "Order" cannot be "int"

order1 = Order(primary_product=1, secondary_product=2)
# error: Value of type variable "T" of "Order" cannot be "int"
```

Unfortunately the generic parameter can now be infered to be exactly `Product`:

```py
product1 = Wrench(color="Yellow")
product2 = Hammer(color="Black")

order = Order(primary_product=product1, secondary_product=product2)  # no error
reveal_type(order)
# Revealed type is 'Order[Product*]'
```

So you **have** to specify the generic type

#### Second way: value restriction

```py
T = TypeVar('T', Hammer, Wrench)
```

Now even this is correctly identified as an error

```py
product1 = Wrench(color="Yellow")
product2 = Hammer(color="Black")

order = Order(primary_product=product1, secondary_product=product2)
# error: Value of type variable "T" of "Order" cannot be "Product"
```

The problem with this approach is obvious: You have to type all the sub classes of `Product` into the `TypeVar` constructor.

#### Third way: factory function

After some experimenting i found a third way that has some odd syntax but combines the advantages of the first two ways. The idea is to force the generic parameter to the type of the first argument.

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Product)

def make_order(primary: P) -> Callable[[P], Order[P]]:
    def inner(secondary: P) -> Order[P]:
        return Order(primary, secondary)
    return inner

make_order(1)(2)
# error: Value of type variable "T" of "make_order" cannot be "int"

product1 = Wrench(color="Yellow")
product2 = Hammer(color="Black")

make_order(product1)(product2)
# Argument 1 has incompatible type "Hammer"; expected "Wrench"

order = make_order(product1)(product1)
reveal_type(order)
# Revealed type is 'Order[Wrench*]'
```

The downsides are:

- strange syntax
- misleading error message ("Argument 1", because it refers to the second call)

To prevent users from directly instantiating `Order` you could rename the class to `_Order`.

Comment: The factory function still doesn't really work, because you could pass it a `Hammer` and a `Wrench` if both objects have static type `Product`. This problem is almost unavoidable through static techniques.

Comment: In languages that support it, one common technique is to have something like `class Product<T extends Product>` and then `class Wrench extends Product<Wrench>` and `class Hammer extends Product<Hammer>`, which then lets you require that two instances of `Product<T>` have the same `T`. Java's `Comparable` works like that, for example. Python doesn't support that kind of recursive type parameter, though.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica i don't understand your first comment. Which case are you refering to? `Order(Product(""), Product(""))`?

Comment: Suppose you have a function that takes two `Product`s, and you pass it `Wrench('yellow')` and `Hammer('black')`. If that function tries to call `make_order` on the objects it received, mypy won't see a problem.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica i see, good point. I would argue however then that the surrounding code is faulty. My approach only solves the wrong inference when i am given the correct types. When i am given the wronge types there is nothing more i can do.

Comment: But `Product` **is** a correct type for a `Wrench` or a `Hammer`. You can't avoid that. The thing that makes this a hard problem is that subclass instances are instances of superclasses, and statically, you don't have enough information about what subclass an object might be an instance of (barring CRTP-style tricks like I mentioned in my second comment, which mypy doesn't support).

Comment: Awesome answer. Although it's not explicitly defined in the code, `Product` is an abstract base class in this use case so I love **Solution #2**.